# Meaning of ring notation $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ in commutative algebra [localization]

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, notation, localization

I am doing some exercises on commutative algebra and came along the following expressions, which were not elaborated on. Is someone familiar with them?

The first is for $p$ a prime number $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, where the exercise is to determine all ideals. Do you think this is just $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

The second one is for $P$ a prime ideal the expression $P_P$, where $P_P$ lies in $R_P$ for $R$ a ring.

I never came across this notation before so I have to ask here.

Comment: No, it means "p-local numbers", the localisation of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This gives no result in Google

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_%28algebra%29. In particular, look at the fourth bullet point of the section "Examples and Applications".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is defined as $\{ \frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}\mid p\nmid b\}$.

In general if $R$ is an integral ring and $P$ a prime ideal, $R_P:= \{ \frac{a}{b}\in\operatorname{Frac}(R)\mid b\not\in P\}$.

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$?

Comment: The quotient field.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ is the localization of $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $p\mathbb Z$.
2. $P_P$ stands for the maximal ideal of $R_P$. Other (better?) notation: $PR_P$.